# php upload script won't work

Tags: php, file, upload

I wanna make uploads of pictures possible on my homepage.
I'm using a script by w3schools to do this:

This is the upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !="jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I already created a folder /var/www/uploads/
When trying to upload a 3KB jpeg i get this output:

```
File is an image - image/jpeg.
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.
Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => Test Bild Website Upload.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpyxW0TX [error] => 0 [size] => 2999 ) )
```

I'm beginner in php and got really no idea what the problem is.
Maybe someone out there can help me with this. :)

Comment: what are your permissions on your " /var/www/uploads/" folder, it will need to be owned by, or writable by your webserver user, most commonly www-data or apache

Comment: Make sure the permission for ` /var/www/uploads/` are set to `755`

Comment: Your `move_uploaded_file` function is returning false. This happens when the file is not a valid upload file OR when the file is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason. Check your permissions for the folder you are uploading to. Maybe you need to ensure you have read write access.

Comment: Where can i change the permissions of the folder? The server is running on Debian 7.
Edit: Just found it on Filezilla. But the problem is still there.

Comment: have you got Filezilla ? just right click on the folder and choose permissions then type 755

Comment: Ok, i was testing a little bit with the permissions, and now it's working! Thanks for the tip, i thought the problem was inside the code ^^

Comment: with all of the other checking you did, you forgot the **MOST IMPORTANT** check: `if ($_FILES['fileToUpload]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("upload failed"); }`. everything else simply assumes an upload occurred, and succeeded, which is exactly the WRONG thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check to see if you can upload the file at all by executing this at the command line:

   `chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads/`
2. Then try to upload something. If that works, you know it was a permissions issue. But you don't want to leave the uploads folder at 777 permission (which give access to everyone)
3. If it was a permissions issue, here is the way I like to do permissions:

   `chown [your username]:www-data -R /var/www/uploads/`

   `chmod -R 775 /var/www/uploads/`

This changes the group assignment of the folder to www-data, which is typically what apache runs as on a Ubuntu linux server.