# PHP File upload not working after completing all the steps. (I think)

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, amazon-ec2

**Here's my background:**

I'm using Amazon EC2 Linux Instance running Apache and LAMP.

I'm trying to make a PHP image upload.

I got the code from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

I have tried signing in as `Superuser (su)` and changing the permissions on the upload folder (`/var/www/html/photo/backend/images/uploads`) to `chmod 755`.

I have tried running `print_r($_FILES);` and get `Array ( )`.

I've changed these things in `php.ini`:

- set `file_uploads` to `on`
- set `max_execution_time` to `300` (seconds)
- set `max_file_size` to `100` (MB)

I've tried and Googled everything I can think of and I still can't figure out why my image doesn't upload. I'm sorry if this is broad, but I really don't know what the problem is.

---

**Issue:**

Image doesn't upload (no idea why, I think I've followed all the steps, see above)

---

Here's my code:

```js
<?php
$target_dir = "/backend/images/uploads";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  print_r($_FILES);
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/backend/images/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for reading, and if anything doesn't make sense, please comment!

Comment: is your server returning any error?

Comment: @RajeshPatel How do I check that? I know how to run commands and open files, etc. But I'm really a noob about server side errors. Thanks!

Comment: after if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {    try var_dump($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);die();

Comment: and let me know is your request is reaching or not?

Comment: Where do I put that code? At the bottom of upload PHP file or do I run it in terminal? Thanks so much for your patience!

Comment: do it after this line:-  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

Comment: It just returns empty html page (nothing at all, not even original `Array ( )`). Did you mis-type it? What should it be doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128126/discussion-between-rajesh-patel-and-jeff-arries).

Answer (score 0):

add `/` after uploads

change

```
$target_dir = "/backend/images/uploads";
```

to below code

```
$target_dir = "/backend/images/uploads/";
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I'm still getting the error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: it is http://emmetstudios.com/backend/images/upload , but it's password protected using .htaccess EDIT: It's not password protected, I got confused.

Comment: Could the problem possibly be that the directory that contains the HTML file is .htaccess password protected?

Comment: BTW the HTML form and the upload.php are different files, incase that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, was deleting things, try it now.

Comment: save the form.html in same folder to sort out the problem.

Comment: Done. but form is called index.html FYI.

Comment: similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837561/php-upload-script-wont-work

Comment: now the error is "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file" have u changed to $target_dir = "/backend/images/uploads/";

Comment: Yes, it says (copied right from file) `$target_dir = "/backend/images/uploads/";`

Comment: I would also encourage you to take a look at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128126/discussion-between-rajesh-patel-and-jeff-arries (this is what else I'm doing)